# SymPy: how to integrate sum of two Piecewise functions without simplification?

Tags: sum, sympy, integral, piecewise

I have a function that is a sum of 3 Piecewise functions:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing()
x = symbols('x')
M = Piecewise((13*x,x>=0),(0,True)) + Piecewise((-15*(x-2),x>=2),(0,True)) + Piecewise((-9*(x-4)**2/2,x>=4),(0,True))
M
```

Output:
[image]

When I integrate this, I get:

```
C_1,EE,II=symbols('C_1,EE,II')
alpha=-1/(EE*II)*(integrate(M,x)+C_1)
alpha
```

Output:
[image]

But I would like the result to be in a form that shows the integral grouped the same way as M, so in 3 groups. Like this, I would hope seeing something like "-9(x-4)^3/6" in the last part.
Is this possible, without having to calculate the integrals for each of the 3 parts of M separately?
I tried to use something like M.piecewise_integrate(x), but that doesn't seem to work on M directly, probably since it is a sum of Piecewises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that is by using the linearity of integrals: you can integrate each addend of `M` separately, and adding the results together.

```py
Add(*[integrate(a, x) for a in M.args])
```

Then you add the constant and multiply by your factors.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works! A side-question: is it possible to let the result be "not elaborated"? So that e.g. the last part shows like -9(x-4)^3/6 instead of −3^3/2+18^2−72+96?

Comment: Try this: `Add(*[integrate(a, x).replace(lambda t: isinstance(t, Add), lambda t: t.factor()) for a in M.args])`

Comment: Wow, thanks! This works like a charm. This result is exactly what my students would find in their hand calculations. The code is now "a bit less intuitive", of course ;-) I hope it won't scare off my students too much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the expression with `replace` and tell it to integrate the `Piecewise` that it finds:

```py
>>> M.replace(
    lambda p: p.is_Piecewise,
    lambda p: integrate(p, x).factor(deep=1))
Piecewise((0, x <= 0), (13*x**2/2, True)) + Piecewise((0, x <= 2), (-15*(x - 2)*
*2/2, True)) + Piecewise((0, x <= 4), (-3*(x - 4)**3/2, True))
```

Comment: Thanks, also this works! But as you can see, I add an integration constant to the result of the integration, C_1, to get alpha(x). And I would like to integrate this alpha(x) again in a similar way, such that C_1*x appears in the result of the second integration. This works automatically with the solution of Davide_sd. Can I achieve the same with your apporach? So that in every integration-run, the constants that I add are integrated also?

Comment: Then integrating the arguments of the Add is the way to go.